# Логическое сложение шестнадцатеричных чисел

Tags: математика

Логическое сложение шестнадцатеричных чисел - как это делается? На эмуляторе VAX, если кто слышал, складывал числа и что-то прояснил немного для себя, но очевидно неправильно. цифры от 0 до 17 складывались так: запоминалось число больше предыдущего. Допустим 14 + 17 = 17. Следующее сложение прошло таким образом: 27 + 17 = 37 0_0 .

Comment: Во-первых, цифры от 0 до F (==15).

Comment: Развейте пожалуйста свою мысль.

Comment: В шестнадцатеричной системе цифры обозначаются символами 0-9, A, B, C, D, E, F, соответствующим по значению десятеричным числам от 0 до 15.

Comment: ДА это знаю, не меняет дела. Все равно ничего не понимаю.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А вы точно уяснили разницу между АРИФМЕТИЧЕСКИМ сложением и ЛОГИЧЕСКИМ ???
Логическое сложение - это функция OR

```
0 or 0 = 0
1 or 0 = 1
0 or 1 = 1
1 or 1 = 1
27 (hex) = 100111 (bin)
17 (hex) = 10111 (bin)
складываем поразрядно
100111
or
010111
=
110111
110111 (bin) = 37 (hex)
```